# Questionamento sobre forma de abertura de array em PHP

Tags: php

Dando um lida sobre arrays em PHP, acabei encontrando algumas formas distintas de se abrir um array, mas que no fim possuem o mesmo destino, exemplo:

```
$arr = [
   'dado' => ''
];
```

Ou

```
$arr = array(
  'dado' => ''
);
```

Ou

```
$arr['dado'] = '';
```

E em outro contexto, adicionando keys:

```
$a = 1;
while($a <= 10){
   $arr[$a] = 'dado'.$a;
   $a++
}
```

Existe alguma diferença relevante nesses diferentes modos de se abrir um array ?

Qual seria o modo mais 'correto' de se abrir um array ?

Comment: As duas últimas não geram o resultado esperado. Quer mesmo mantê-las na pergunta? Acho que, considerando o foco da discussão, as mesmas poderiam ser removidas.

Comment: Eu não cheguei a testar pra ver se o retorno é o mesmo, acho que da pra remover sim.

Comment: Procure sobre linguagens dinâmicas. Que é o caso do PHP, ele vai dar o tipo da variável no momento da atribuição do valor para ela. Como você declarou o array em 3 formas, ele vai entender que a variável é do tipo array. Acontece o mesmo com o javascript que tem tipagem dinâmica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim existe (quando usar, ambos geram o mesmo resultado um array.), a sintaxe compacta (`[]`)  só está disponível a partir do 5.4 para versões anterios apenas `array()` funciona. Para manter maior compatibilidade do código caso seja uma biblioteca recomenda-se o uso da sintaxe tradicional `array()`.